# C++ array of structures initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, initialization

I have the following structure:

```
struct localframepos
{
    double ipos; //local room frame i(x) coordinate, in mm
    double cpos; //local room frame c(y) coordinate, in mm
    double rpos; //local room frame r(z) coordinate, in mm

    localframepos()
    {
        ipos = 0;
        cpos = 0;
        rpos = 0;
    }
    localframepos(double init_ipos, double init_cpos, double init_rpos) //init constructor
    {
        ipos = init_ipos;
        cpos = init_cpos;
        rpos = init_rpos;
    } 
};
```

**How do I get the following functionality:**

```
localframepos positions[] = { {0, .5, .2},
                              {4.5, 4, .5} };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the constructors. To use curly brace initialization, the type has to be a POD.

Comment: Why C++11, this is simple aggregate initialization.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Plain Old Data

Comment: @JesseGood does C++03 support intializing arrays with pod's?

Comment: -1 "To use curly brace initialization, the type has to be a POD." is incorrect for C++03 (any aggregate can be initialized with curly braces syntax), and it is even more incorrect for C++11.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use

```
localframepos positions[] = { localframepos(0  , .5, .2),
                              localframepos(4.5, 4, .5) };
```

which is not that nice looking, but much more flexible if you need different initialization possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

For C++03 you can write

```
localframepos positions[] = { localframepos( 0, .5, .2 ),
                              localframepos( 4.5, 4, .5 ) };
```